# ADO.NET Entity Model and LINQ using JOINs

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, join, entity-framework-6

My query:

```
using (var context = new consoleApp.JohnDoe_dbEntities())
        {
            var data= (from lo in context.tbl_loans
                         join doc in context.tbl_docinfo on lo.idDocInfo equals doc.idDocInfo
                         join insp in context.tbl_inspections on lo.idLoan equals insp.idLoan
                         where insp.StatusInspections == 3 && lo.idLoan == 5
                         select new
                         {
                             lo,
                             doc,
                             insp
                         });}
```

I want to access every column from tbl_idLoans, tbl_docinfo and tbl_inspections example: "lo.CityName". I don't understand how i could access them using the LINQ syntax. The current query is correct except the SELECT part onwards, i don't know if it's doing what i want which is give me access to every column on all three tables where the conditions apply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your table properties a name in your `select` statement. By doing so, you should be able to select a column from any table in the `data` object by using the syntax `data.FirstOrDefault().Inspection.StatusInspections`, `data.FirstOrDefault().Loan.idLoan`, etc.

```
var data = (from lo in context.tbl_loans
            join doc in context.tbl_docinfo on lo.idDocInfo equals doc.idDocInfo
            join insp in context.tbl_inspections on lo.idLoan equals insp.idLoan
            where insp.StatusInspections == 3 && lo.idLoan == 5
            select new
            {
                Loan = lo,
                DocInfo = doc,
                Inspection = insp
            });
```

Comment: I can't test it because of an error "Mysql.Data.Types.MySqlConversionException: Unable to convert MySql data/time value to System.DateTime"; 
A console print like this:                                                                                            **Console.WriteLine("data: " + data.FirstOrDefault().Loan.CityName);**  would print the only value available ex. "Florida"?